# Tensorflow not utilizing GPU

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am currently trying to train a chat bot, more specifically [this one](https://github.com/daniel-kukiela/nmt-chatbot). But when I start to train the chat bot it utilizes 100% of my CPU and roughly 10% of my GPU. Does someone possibly have an idea why.

[image: GPU utilization]
[image: CPU utilization]

I have installed `tensorflow-gpu` and have made sure I have the correct version of CUDA and cuDNN. I have also made sure that I do not have the base `tensorflow` pip package installed. I also have the latest Nvidia drivers for my GPU. I have also tried uninstalling and re-installing all my drivers, CUDA, cuDNN, tensorflow-gpu and all its dependencies and python itself - which none of it worked.

I can create a python script and include `with tf.device('/gpu:0');` and create a graph with it without issue, so it is definitely detecting the GPU but just doesn't seem to utilize it.

When running `sess = tf.Session(config=tf.ConfigProto(log_device_placement=True))` I get an output of the following:

> 2019-05-22 16:47:00.168170: I
>   C:\tf_jenkins\workspace\rel-win\M\windows-gpu\PY\36\tensorflow\core\platform\cpu_feature_guard.cc:137]
>   Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not
>   compiled to use: AVX AVX2
>
> 2019-05-22 16:47:00.433514: I
>   C:\tf_jenkins\workspace\rel-win\M\windows-gpu\PY\36\tensorflow\core\common_runtime\gpu\gpu_device.cc:1105]
>   Found device 0 with properties:
>
> name: GeForce GTX 1060 with Max-Q Design major: 6 minor: 1
>   memoryClockRate(GHz): 1.48
>
> pciBusID: 0000:01:00.0
>
> totalMemory: 6.00GiB freeMemory: 4.97GiB
>
> 2019-05-22 16:47:00.450094: I
>   C:\tf_jenkins\workspace\rel-win\M\windows-gpu\PY\36\tensorflow\core\common_runtime\gpu\gpu_device.cc:1195]
>   Creating TensorFlow device (/device:GPU:0) -> (device: 0, name:
>   GeForce GTX 1060 with Max-Q Design, pci bus id: 0000:01:00.0, compute
>   capability: 6.1)
>
> Device mapping:
>
> /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 -> device: 0, name:
>   GeForce GTX 1060 with Max-Q Design, pci bus id: 0000:01:00.0, compute
>   capability: 6.1
>
> 2019-05-22 16:47:01.391802: I
>   C:\tf_jenkins\workspace\rel-win\M\windows-gpu\PY\36\tensorflow\core\common_runtime\direct_session.cc:297]
>   Device mapping:
>
> /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 -> device: 0, name:
>   GeForce GTX 1060 with Max-Q Design, pci bus id: 0000:01:00.0, compute
>   capability: 6.1

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't look like there's any issue with your GPU setup (especially if you can confirm the GPU is used more when you train than when you don't, using `nvidia-smi` for example)

Note however that **your GPU is not necessarily going to be the bottleneck in your training**, meaning that some CPU-only intensive compute like data augmentation might just be so slow that your GPU gets underutilized.

I'd advise profiling your training code to see what's taking all that CPU power.